# Can't view reports on client's machine browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I definetely stuck here because i've tried almost everything on these posts but no luck yet.

Sepcs:
Server: Windows Server 2008 Foundation Edition (IIS7)
Client Machine OS: Windows XP Pro
Cristal Report ver: 13.0.2
Devolpment: Visual Studio 2010, Web Applications using ASPNET

Problem
I can't view reports on client machine

Background:
I installed crystal reports 13.0.2 on my server and start creating my reports on VS2010 without any problem, even if i compile the web project it works fine, it shows the reports perfectly. As you know when you do that, Visual Studio creates a virtual port to let you try your application.

But when i try to do it from the browser (not using compilation from VS2010) it is not showing reports, i don't see any errors either, even on the server it self, simply doesn't show any report.

Descrption

I have a web application using framework 4 and its under Default Website http://myserver:10000/novo/myapp/default.aspx.
Im using DefaultAppPool in Intregrated mode (also i already tried classic mode)

I copied crystalReportViewer13 directory from wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\, to my web application directory

also, i verified that crystalreportviewers13 directory has been created under windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETClientFiles

After i red SAP Crystal Reports SDK Developers Guide i did this:

on my web.config file i have these tags:

```
<add key="url" value="http://localhost:10000/novo/myapp/printcontrol.cab" />
<add key="resourceURI" value="~/crystalreportviewers13"
```

On Desing Mode, under CrystalReportViewer Properties i have PrintMode=ActiveX

And finally i've added my web site on the trusted sites on Internet Explorer and custom all features allowing to install any ActiveX control.

Everything i've done is useless still can't see reports on server or Client Machine browser.

PLEASE HELP ME OUT HERE-----I'M STUCKED, i've spent a lot of time appying some recomendation from this Forum, i don't know what else to do.

Comment: Try using a tool like Fiddler (http://http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the request that your browser is sending out, and the response (if any) that is coming back from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser?  What viewer?

At work, we use both IE (and old version) and FF.  With the DHTML viewer, either should work.  With other viewers, if the user workstation has improper security settings, then the ActiveX viewer and/or Java Viewer may not work correctly.

In FF, there is a FireBug plug-in that I use a lot.  There's a lot that you can see about web page requests, what's loading slowly, what the headers are, etc.  (It's a lot more than I can use, and I actually look at it to help hack style sheets or see what sections of a page a holding up loading, more than anything else.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been encountering this problem and searching and almost does the procedure stated above,
i've notice that the aspnet_client is not configure in my IIS and cannot access all files under "crystalreportviewers13".

I solve this problem by registering the aspnet in IIS using using this procedure.

register aspnet:

c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

and done!! 
my application already accessing files under "crystalreportviewers13"

thanks,
bryan